# How to pass POST parameter in retrofit API method?

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I am writing my first code in `Retrofit 1.9` version. I tried to follow several blog but not able to understand very basic problem. So far, I have created `Model` class using `jsonschema2pojo`, `RestAdapter` class.

Here is my model class:

```
@Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")
public class GmailOauth {

@Expose
private String createdAt;
@Expose
private String objectId;
@Expose
private String sessionToken;
@Expose
private String username;

.....  Getter and Setter methods...
```

I have created above `model` class using `Jsonschema2pojo`. So, my response JSON is very understandable.

## Adapter class

```
public class RestApiAdapter {
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://testingserver.com:8081";
public RestAdapter providesRestAdapter(Gson gson) {
    return new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(BASE_URL)
            .build();
   }
}
```

## API class

```
interface GmailSignInAPI {

@POST("/signWithGmail")
void GmailOauthLogin(@Body GmailOauth user, Callback<GmailOauth> cb);

}
```

Now, I am confused how to write `Retrofit` client to pass `following` form-data post parameter in efficient way?

```
accessToken  (String value)
userID       (String value)
```

How about if I want to pass custom object in a post request and save the response of request in same object? Is this good way to do it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think for the api portion of Retrofit I would put

```
 @FormUrlEncoded
    @Post("/path/to/whatever")
    void authenticateWithSomeCredentials(@Field("username") String userName, Callback<Object> reponse
```

Then I would call it like this:

```
public void authenticateWithSomeCredentials(username), new Callback<Object>() {

   @Override
   public void success(Object object, Response response) {
   // Do something
    }

   @Override
   public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    // Do something
    }

}
```

To add the token to every call you could add an interceptor:

```
public class YourAuthInterceptor implements interceptor {

@Override
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
     request = chain.request().newBuilder()
     .addHeader("token"), tokenVariable)
     .build();
return chain.proceed(request);
    }
}
this will add a "token" to every call you make with retrofit

so then when you build your api you build it like this

YourApi api = new RestAdapter.Builder()
            .setEndpoint(url)
            .setRequestInterceptor(new YourAuthInterceptor())
            .build()
            .create(YourApi.class);
```

I hope this makes sense as I am typing it rather quickly.  If you have any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("/postTosServer")
    void postToServer(@Field("accessToken") String your_token, @Field("userID") String userid);
```

Comment: Thanks Aakash but how to write `RestClient` for that. I mean How can I pass these parameters from Client? Also can I pass custom object to the request?
Also what about the model class?

Comment: @komal Josh have answered your another query.